# BLE Restoration/Preservation unexpected effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, state-restoration

I have implemented restoration functionality for `CoreBluetooth` and it works fine, except one thing - after a week (+/- - not sure for 100%) in the background, without opening, app terminated and not restored anymore on any BLE-based events (tested few times).

I also add logging to all BLE related task, add analytic for capturing crashes, track restoring process/events in additional - and after checking this logs/info/reports - not found any exceptions or something that can terminate my app.

The question is - can someone explain me the reason why I got such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth related issues can be really hard to identify. We came across several unexplainable bugs in the past. The only way to determine why BLE was no longer working or misbehaving was to look at the CoreBluetooth logs on the device.

In case you have not tried that already you can enable these logs via a configuration profile that you can download from the [Apple Developer Pages](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?platform=ios) (look for Bluetooth and follow the instructions).

As soon as you enable the logging you can download a complete log from the underlying BLE stack that will tell you what went wrong. They even tell you if you have misused the API in some way. Hope that helps.

Comment: oh, that should help, event don't think about such possibility

Comment: Yeah, it is one of the hidden treasures of iOS development. Be prepared to read a lot of C++ logging for the bluetooth stack ;-).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with CoreBluetooth State Preservation and Restoration I have come to the conclusion that it does not work reliably. You can get it working sort of "ok", but you will never get it to reconnect reliably while using long running pending connections in the background.

I have reported several bugs regarding this, but the most serious one in my opinion is that If the bluetooth manager switches state while the app is terminated then all pending connections will be lost (since they are not remembered by the module or the iOS stack). Since bluetooth state switches will not cause your app to be relaunched then it simply means that at any point in time your pending connection can be lost and you will not know about it. This on its own effectively means that State Restoration is rather useless. You could say that this is not a bug, but rater a poor design choice…

Another one is that sometimes the framework gets ”stuck” in a bad state (possibly by an internal race-condition or similar). This can happen randomly, but you can pretty easily reproduce this by calling connectPeripheral immediately in the didFailToConnect or didDisconnect callback. When this happens the connectionState will be set to connecting while in fact it is not.

And so on…

/Anton